# why doesn't generic map work?

Tags: java, generics

```
class MyMap<K,V> {

   private Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<K,V>();
   ...

   public void add(K key, V value){
      map.put(key,value);
   }

   private load(String filePath){
      ...
      while(true){
        ...
        People key = new People();
        Information info = new Information();
        ...
       this.add(key, info);
     }
   }
}
```

It complains that:

```
add(K,V) is not applicable for the arguments "[People, Information]".
```

Comment: private Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<K,V>();

Comment: I haven't started to use it outside of it. I am seeing the error in the load method, "this.add(people, info)"; This class itself is already reporting error.

Comment: I don't think this should be generic, if what you're storing is always `People` keys and `Information` values.

Comment: No. This MyMap is supposed to work with other types too and that's why I want generics here.

Comment: If it's supposed to work with other types, then remove the line where you add a `People` and an `Information`.

Comment: Then probably the whole load() method should be outside of it?

Comment: You should have someone create a `MyMap<People,Information>` and load data in it.  Just think, if someone created a `MyMap<Foo, Bar> myMap`, and called `myMap.load()`, how can it make sense?

Comment: A generic map should hold generic types. If you're not storing generic data, why are you using generics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correct way to exercise this class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyMap<People, Information> map = new MyMap<>();
        People p = new People();
        Information i = new Information();
        map.add(p, i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to insert directly the value into the Hash map without specif the generic that it will give compile time error